# Как настроить файловый сервер, сервер впн и сервер авторизации

Tags: vpn, сервер

Хочу настроить файловый сервер, сервер впн и сервер авторизации, но не знаю с чего начать и  как продолжить. Пожалуйста, подскажите литературу!

Answer (score 1):

Определитесь для начала с технологиями и целями.

- OS
- файловый сервер для чего ? (nfs/smb/dcpp/bittorrent/btsync/еще что нить)
- vpn для чего ? (openvpn/pppoe/ipsec)
- сервер авторизации для чего ? (ldap/RADIUS/kerberos/OpenID)

---

По всем этим вещам вполне нормально начать с википедии и углубляться по ссылкам.